# How to upgrade exim4 without losing configuration settings

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, exim

Using Ubuntu 14.04 is there a way to upgrade exim4 without losing configuration? Preferably through apt.

Upon running `apt-get --simulate upgrade` it shows the package will be upgraded to `4.82-3ubuntu2.4`, however the latest version appears to be 4.93 according to [exim.org].

Would the easiest solution be to compile this from source, copying any config files currently in place and just hope that they work with the new version?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 reached its end-of-life last year (except for Canonical's Extended Security Maintenance customers). You should consider upgrading the whole system to Ubuntu 16.04. Can you clarify why do you need to upgrade to a cutting-edge version of **Exim**?

Comment: I completely agree, however due to circumstances (this being a production server) this will have to be scheduled in. We're looking to upgrade Exim first due to a number of CVSS 10 vulnerabilities affecting the installed version which can lead to full compromise of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration of **exim4** is quite backwards compatible, although the maintainers of the [exim4-config](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/exim4-config) improve the rules from time to time (unfortunately the changelog is common for all **exim4** packages).

I think your best choice is to upgrade to the [xenial-updates package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/exim4-daemon-heavy): the minimal versions of its dependencies are quite old, even from an Ubuntu 14.04 perspective, and it covers all [recent vulnerabilities](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/e/exim4/exim4_4.86.2-2ubuntu2.5/changelog). You might get away with just upgrading the `exim4-*` packages.

You just need to:

1. Add the `xenial-updates` repositories to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main
   ```
2. Set the default release to `trusty` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

   ```
   APT::Default-Release "trusty";
   ```
3. [Pin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) the `exim4*` packages in `/etc/apt/preferences`:

   ```
   Package: exim4*
   Pin: release n="xenial"
   Priority: 900
   ```
4. Normally upgrade the `exim4` package:

   ```
   apt update
   apt install exim4
   ```

A normal upgrade process will not overwrite your configuration files, but it is better to make a backup. Afterwards you might want to merge the `*.dpkg-dist` files into your configuration.